# How to change encoding of MS Access 2010 Database Project source files

Tags: ms-access, encoding, ms-access-2010

I have and .adp file that was created on PC with **iso-8859-2** default codepage.
When I try to open in on another PC with different codepage, the VBA won't compile.

Is there a way to convert the encoding? I'm not interested in data as those are in SQL Server. I only need to convert the sources.

Comment: Have you tried converting ADP file to MDB or ACCDB?

Comment: Not really. It is a huge project with hundreds of forms and hundred thousand lines of VBA so I doubt it will be so easy

Comment: What version of Access are you using? Access 2013 and later can NOT open adp files. you need access 2010 (or previous).

Comment: I've installed Acces 2010, of course. I'm able to open the file

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that AFTER 2010, you can't open the adp files. So this issue is not likely due to regional settings or a different iso code page, but that of simply using a version of Access AFTER 2010 (they can't open adp files - nothing, zero to do with code page).

so, you need Access 2010 (or earlier), and you can then create a blank database, and import all of the forms, reports and code modules from that ADP file. (I recommend that you don't even open the adp - just import everything you want into a blank new accDB file.

You don't mention what version of Access you have, but for reading (or importing which is MUCH better approach), then you need Access 2010 (or previous) to open that ADP file. And as noted, I would create a blank accDB file, and use the external tab in the ribbon and IMPORT the forms, reports and all code modules. That will give you the ability to salvage all the reports, forms, and code modules - including the VBA code behind.

and of course if the file format is a ade, then you are in big trouble, since that format has all of the source code stripped out, and the source code is not included in a ade file. So you need Access 2010.

Comment: I do have access 2010 and I can open it, but it only works when with specific encoding set in Windows, otherwise I get VBA compiler errors.